# How to expose a variable from one method within a controller.js to another controller.js with javascript express node

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mean-stack, meanjs

I have an Mongo, Express, Angular, Node application. I am trying to pass a variable that is a response of a method in 1 file to a different method in a different file.

So during a series of user actions it triggers a method `exports.test` inside the `test.controller.js` file

looks like this:

```
exports.test = function(req, res) {

        var query = 'crazy query'
        var params = { key:value }
        var cb = function(err,stuff) {
            });
            res.json(stuff);
        var testOutput = res.json(stuff);
        return testOutput;  
    }
        sendToServer(query,params,cb);
}
```

Notice how I have set testOutput equal to the response from the server. And I have returned testOutput, from the method.

Now I was curious, I have another controller `actions.controller.js`. And inside of this file I have a method called `exports.actions`
looks like this:

```
exports.actions = function(req, res, testOutput) {
        console.log(testOutput);

        var query = 'crazy query'
        var params = { key:value }
        var cb = function(err,stuff) {
            });
            res.json(stuff);
    }
        sendToServer(query,params,cb);
}
```

I am trying to expose var testOutput from test.controller.js to actions.controller.js, so I can pass `testOutput` as an argument into the `exports.actions` method. Is this possible?

Comment: can you show the way you are handling your routes in express for these functions? Seems like you want to use a middleware.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot directly expose any variable to other controllers. Communication between controllers can happen via services.

Define a service to update and save the value of testOutput:

```
angular.module('myApp',[])
.factory('myService',function(){
var init = {};
init.update = function(newVal) {
init.testOutput = newVal;
};
return init;
}]);
```

Your controllers:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.controller('Ctrl1',['myService',function(myService){
exports.test = function(req, res) {

    var query = 'crazy query'
    var params = { key:value }
    var cb = function(err,stuff) {
        });
        res.json(stuff);
    var testOutput = res.json(stuff);
    myService.update(testOutput);  
}
    sendToServer(query,params,cb);
}
}]);

angular.module('myApp')
.controller('Ctrl2',['myService',function(myService){
exports.actions = function(req, res) {
    console.log(mapService.testOutput); //use the variable as u like

    var query = 'crazy query'
    var params = { key:value }
    var cb = function(err,stuff) {
        });
        res.json(stuff);
}
    sendToServer(query,params,cb);
}
}]);
```